# Induced charge on a shell

Tags: electrostatics

If a charge +Q is placed off-center inside a neutral conducting shell,can we comment that the charges induced on the inner surface is such that the  net force on the +Q charge is zero?If so,how?

Answer (score 1):

First, electric fields add linearly, such that the total field inside the shell is the field due to the shell + the field due to the charge. So we can deal with each separately. Let us imagine our shell has radius $R$.

The charge inside will induce a charge on the shell. Let us deal with that alone since as we've said electric fields obey a linear superposition principle, so IGNORE THE CHARGED PARTICLE. Let us imagine a spherical gaussian surface of radius $ r' < R $. Gauss' law says that the electric flux through the surface is proportional to the charge bounded by the surface, which is our imaginary gaussian sphere of radius $r'$. But there is no charge inside this sphere, and the sphere has spherical symmetry so E is perpendicular to dA, so the electric flux and thus the electric field due to the shell is 0.

Now, again using the linearity principle. We can add back in the point charge. But here is no electric field inside the shell. So the charge feels no force.